# Windows: How do I get the mode/access rights of an already opened file?

Tags: windows, api

I am writing a program that is using a database library. The library provides me access to the file handle it uses to access my table. I've found a windows API that allows me to retrieve information about the file by handle but I've yet to find any means of determining access mode / permissions of that file. At this point I'm sure I could likely live without knowing this information but being the stubborn cuss that I am I'm not ready to let this one go. Obviously Windows knows this info - so the question is how can coax the info out of it?

The API function that I've found is: GetFileInformationByHandleEx and it takes me close to the watering hole but doesn't let me drink the water.

The reason that the file mode information is useful is that I need to modify the table header information. If the file is already in a proper mode then I won't have to close the table open the file modify the file close the file then re-open the table.

And yes, before I'm told of all the options available to me to achieve my goal - I'm not interested in those. I'm only interesting in the original question - how do I determine the mode of an already opened file. I look forward to any responses and I thank you in advance.

Thanks,
Robert Milligan

Comment: You can try writing something to such file, if it fails then you must reopen it. Not sure if WinAPI provides such function from user space, and I doubt you would want to write driver to just export such functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a corresponding Win32 API for this, but if you really need it you can call NtQueryObject(ObjectBasicInformation).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm using    qResult := NtQueryInformationFile(
      DataSet.DBFHandle.FileHandle,
      ioStatus,
      AccessInfo,
      SizeOf( AccessInfo ),
      ficFileAccessInformation
   );

Answer (score 1):

OK. So I finally got this part all figured out - thanks to your direction, a lot of MSDN study and a LOT of trial and error.

There were a couple of tricky points to getting this all figured out.

1) The ACCESS_MASK certainly did not reflect the access modes as I expected. The documentation led me to expect the upper 4 bits to reflect the "GENERIC" modes that I opened the file with - wrong!  Those show up in the Specific Rights section. Heck - I still don't have a clue when those upper 4 bits actually get used, but for this exercise I don't need to.

2) Once I got THAT clear in my mind I had to stumble across documentation that let me know that when I opened with GENERIC_READ that was translated into:

FILE_GENERIC_READ

which is made up of:

STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ |
   FILE_READ_DATA |
   FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES |
   FILE_READ_EA |
   SYNCHRONIZE

Understanding this concept made all the rest of it fall into place. Now my understanding correlated with the information that Process Hacker was telling me.

3) I also had a serious error going from my UI to the code (read one constant misplaced), which once figured out made the whole world lay down before my feet.

This is great because I can now figure out what Access Modes were used when the file was opened.  Original question answered!

Now I would like to be able to determine the "share" mode the file is in - if possible. Any ideas?

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out maybe? From my reading of the docs, it seems you might be able to discern the original "share mode" of an open handle by calling [ReOpenFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-reopenfile) with `dwDesiredAccess` of `0` and `dwShareMode` for one (or more?) of the modes to query, i.e. `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`, `FILE_SHARE_READ`, `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`.  If `ReOpenFile` returns a valid handle--which you can then close/dispose--then that sharing mode was present on the original file?

*Source*:

> "If `dwDesiredAccess` is zero (0), the application can query device attributes without accessing the device. This is useful if an application wants to determine the size of a floppy disk drive and the formats it supports without requiring a floppy in the drive."
> <sub>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-reopenfile</sub>

Comment: There's a share-access record that's part of the common filesystem context for all kernel file objects that reference a given filesystem file or directory. The share-access record contains 7 counters: 1 counter for the number of times a file is open with data access; 3 counters for the number of times it's open with read/execute, write/append, or delete data access; and 3 counters for the number of opens that share read/execute, write/append, and delete data access. If an open does not request data access, then the share-access record is not checked and is not updated.

Comment: Process Explorer shows the `SharedRead`, `SharedWrite`, and `SharedDelete` flags of a [file object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_object), which are set when it's created in order to be able decrement the share-access counters when the file object is cleaned up when it's no longer referenced. From user mode there's no way to inspect these flags. Since a new open uses the common share-access record that takes account of all opens, there's no way to infer the flags for a particular open.