# Change sharing mode of existing HANDLE

Tags: c++, winapi

When creating a file through [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), we can specify the sharing mode using the `DWORD dwShareMode` parameters.

But is it possible to change the sharing mode on an already open HANDLE, similar to how [LockFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) works on an already open HANDLE (note - LockFile is not the same as changing the sharing mode, that's why I can't just use it).

Comment: You could use ReOpenFile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365497.aspx if you don't mind getting a new handle

Comment: @manuell The problem is I want to change the underlying `HANDLE` of a `FILE` opened by third-party code. That `FILE` would still be referencing the old `HANDLE`.

Comment: No. There is no Win32 API change the sharing mode of a handle once it has been opened (that I know of anyway).

Comment: @William Ok, but is there at least a way to detect or find out what the original `FILE_SHARE` mode was, given just an open handle? [NtQueryInformationFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile) can recover the prevailing `FILE_ACCESS` bits, but I don't seem to see the share flags.

Comment: @William For example, am I on to something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54048423/147511)? Do you happen to know if what I propose there is feasible?

Comment: @GlennSlayden I'm mostly guessing here, but it looks like [NtQueryObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryobject) with `ObjectBasicInformation` may return the information in the `Attributes` field of the structure. But, I'm really just guessing based on the fact that Process Explorer will show the share flags for file handles and I think it's just asking the object manager for the information.